# Nested objects intellisense with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am trying to write a function that allows me to import colors into projects more easily and make it more reusable. However, the function is only autocompleting with the 'DEFAULT' value, even though with some colors there are multiple nested variables. What am I missing?

```js
import { get } from 'lodash'

const colors = {
  grey: {
    DEFAULT: '#BFBFBF',
    secondary: '#EDEDED',
    tertiary: '#F7F7F7',
    quaternary: '#4D4D4D',
  },
  white: {
    DEFAULT: '#ffffff',
  },
  black: {
    DEFAULT: '#2B2929',
  },
  green: {
    DEFAULT: '#06757F',
    pale: '#E7F9F7',
  },
  red: {
    DEFAULT: '#E36D6D',
    secondary: '#EFCCCC',
  },
  yellow: {
    secondary: '#FFF2B2',
    DEFAULT: '#FFD300',
  },
  aqua: {
    DEFAULT: '#06757F',
    secondary: '#E7F9F7',
  },
  error: {
    DEFAULT: '#E36D6D',
  },
  success: {
    DEFAULT: '#366855',
  },
}

type Color = keyof typeof colors
type Variant = keyof (typeof colors)[Color]

type ColorName = `${Color}.${Variant}` | Color

export const getColor = (color: ColorName) => {
  return get(colors, color, get(colors, `${color}.DEFAULT`)) 
}
```

When I highlight `Variant` on line 42, it only displays 'DEFAULT'.

[FUNCTION WHEN SELECTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V8H4.png)

Comment: Maybe you need to define the ColorName [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcwKbwL5wGZQiOAcgBsIATAQwGcALQgKHoGMIA7K+F0qKuAXkT04KKKgCeALkHDhAEQCiAMQCCAVQAyAFSmEAxACFFhw4QA0QmVVQtWlKJKK75Cl2YvCYqWMAr2duxQB2IKC3YQxzYS88KCkEdzgFFQ1tR3kAZgA2WWywuAiLKgBXJiZUKio4hKS1LX8szIAOAFZmvIKMRhgxMFQ4AGEIbn44AGtxCGw4bt7JuC5oKi6evsHuADkKED6BNeg4AB9pOABtfrhgVjGJqZnUOYWeAF0pAAMAEgR+jAA6T-kAB5MYhFMioAA8gJgUAoTBg4PGYjmdweQ0WZyepjgHCgl2QAD4sQAiGopIn4jCvegYE6I5ErVHcKhPRioAGQWDzNgcFDoPZQEYACkeUn5m22AEp+PjjqIYEUoFc0DBhWieFjHljlaqmViPghHr9SVpXhKpdT6EA)